# Insert an HTML form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a problem with my program. When I click on my button I want to make my form appear. But here is the error I get when I click on my button:

> "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal"

Can you help me please ?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#modifier').click(function(){
        $('#modification').append('{{form}}');
        $('#test').show()
    });
});
```

The `'{{form}}'` is `django` which is the equivalent of:

```html
'<tr><th><label for="id_commentaire">Commentaire:</label></th><td><textarea name="commentaire" required maxlength="200" rows="10" cols="40" id="id_commentaire">
</textarea></td></tr>'
```

I do not understand where this error comes from.

Thank you in advance.

Yours sincerely,

Comment: Possibly because you have new line in a string

Comment: Thx, I use |escapejs and it works.